# Metro framework creating custom tile c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I need a help. I want to make my own tile which will be containing database data (post, date, title). I want to make tile (or if it's easier) button. It has to generate while run time, so sometimes it should create 5 tiles, sometimes 50 tiles. Im trying to make it in flowlayoutpanel. Height will be set accodring to text lenght, width will be static.

It would be good to make tiles height also static with short title and after click on tile it expend.

Sorry for my english. Thank you for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously... Create a new object "DevComponents.DotNetBar.Metro.MetroTileItem"

then get a little function going for your mass of Tiles you want..

newMetroTile.TitleText = "My new title + i";
newMetroTile.Text = "Bla bla bla";

etc after your tile customizations.. add it to your metro tile/panel

metroTilePanel1.Items.add(newMetroTile);

wala.. your done. I hope you understand.. I'm not too much of a spoon feeder.